# LINQ expression to generate a list of days between two dates

Tags: c#, linq

I have a start and an end date and I want to get a list of all the days between those 2 dates (inclusive). I can do this with a loop that adds 1 day to the start date then adds that date to a list. Something like:

```
DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
DateTime start = end.AddDays(-30);
DateTime current = start;
List<DateTime> result = new List<DateTime>();
while (currrent <= end)
{
    result.Add(current);
    current = current.AddDays(1);
}
```

I'm looking for a tidy LINQ expression instead. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Enumerable.Range` would be one option:

```
var rightNow = DateTime.Now;
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 30).Select(d => rightNow.AddDays(d)).ToList()
```

Comment: Keep in mind, you'd want `Enumerable.Range(0, 30)` if you want `rightNow` included in the collection.

Comment: Yea I like this, just figured I should have a neat 1 liner

Answer (score 6):

If you know the start and end, it's simple just to write a method using an iterator block to do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> DateRange(DateTime startInclusive, DateTime endInclusive)
{
    for (var current = startInclusive; current <= endInclusive; current = current.AddDays(1))
    {
        yield return current;
    }
}
```

If you know the number of days instead, then Cory's answer works well.

My method above could also be overloaded to take a `TimeSpan` for the "step" between iterations.